# How to make mksh (or any other shell) prompt for password in android

Tags: android, bash, authentication, console

I'm trying to add a security layer to my android embedded device. I need to disable/enable access to the android shell. Naturally I thought about using a password, just like linux uses when 'sudo'ing to root.

Does any one have any idea how to do that?

Comment: How did you replace it and are you running SEAndroid?